# CSS Selector Clarification: |= vs ^=

Tags: css, css-selectors

[According to W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

`[foo|='bar']` "Selects all elements with a [foo] attribute starting with "bar"
and 
`[foo^='bar']` "Selects every element whose [foo] attribute value begins with "bar"

In my application, I have inputs with IDs "Input-123456", etc.

Selecting them with `input[id^="Input-"]` works, whereas `input[id|='Input-']` returns nothing.

So what's the difference?

Comment: This is why we don't like w3schools...

Comment: @JosephMarikle, the answer below is not better in any way. It is confusing and obfuscating just in the same way. Also, it is hard to work with non-practical oriented specifications, while the w3school is work ready. It is very convenient while working.

Comment: [MDN Reference -**Attribute selectors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the "real" reference ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)):

> `E[foo^="bar"]` an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"
>
> `E[foo|="en"]` an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"

Always go to the actual standard when there appears to be an inconsistency.  I tend to avoid w3schools because their quality control is sometimes less than stellar.

Comment: Completely agreed.  W3C is hard to navigate, but it is (or is supposed to be) the standard.  MDN (which has a [nice section on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) btw) is good too, but w3schools always seems to disappoint.

Comment: W3C is the place to go indeed, though I go to css-tricks.net occasionally because I like their examples.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I have found w3schools to be a great reference for simple things, but I am noticing more and more subtleties that they get wrong like this. Kind of annoying imho.

Comment: Could you, please, help me to understand it better. The `[foo^="bar"]` will select an element with the following attribute declaration: `foo="bar"`, while the `foo|="bar"` won\`t select the element, since it requires a hyphen to be present in the attribute value. So, for the element to be matched by both of these selectors its attribute declaration can be the following: `foo="bar-"`. Am I right? If I understand it wrong and I am not right, then your answer lacks correctness, since my statement above does not contradict your answer.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a definition for the dash separated list? E.g. is an empty string considered to be a dash separated list?

Answer (score 2):

https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

See |= section, the difference is in the dash separated list.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a definition for the dash separated list? E.g. is an empty string considered to be a dash separated list?