# javascript syntax / put two items in one $ syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quick question.
How can I put two items in $ syntax? for example,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#loading_gif' && '#logo_img').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
```

I just put '&&' and did not work. 
there should be a simple way i guess. 
Thanks!

Comment: `$("#loading_gif    ,     #logo_img")`. jQuery accepts all CSS Selectors.

Comment: Not usually one to recommend W3Schools, but this is a [pretty decent list](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for reference

Comment: @mhodges I think the only usefull thing on w3schools are those CSS Selectors lists. I use them all the time as reference.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Although even then, [they still can be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370441/css-selector-clarification-vs) xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading_gif, #logo_img').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
 });
```

**jQuery** is using a library called [SizzleJS](https://sizzlejs.com/) which allows you to use basic CSS selectors to find the elements in the DOM.
You can use `'#loading_gif, #logo_img'` as a selector while writing your CSS to style both of those elements with their respective ids.

#### [Example](http://jsbin.com/netigewaxo/edit?js,output)

Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#loading_gif, #logo_img').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
```

is the correct way.  && is a Javascript logical operator.  Read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators).

Comment: Definitely a logical operator, not a comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for multi select is

```
 $('#loading_gif,#logo_img').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
```