# What is the difference between | and ^ Selector?

Tags: css

In W3 Schools selectors refrence they have written

```
[attribute|=value] [lang|=en]
```

Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en"

```
[attribute^=value] a[href^="https"]
```

Selects every `<a>` element whose href attribute value begins with `https`

So what is the diffrence between them if they both select an element starting with a word?

Comment: Good question. This already has good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370441/css-selector-clarification-vs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between pipe (|) and caret (^) attribute selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530852/what-is-the-difference-between-pipe-and-caret-attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the difference by yourself. They both look for attribute values starting with some value. However, using |= you need the whole word (or the word separated by a hyphen - from the next word) to be selected. Example:

```
<h1 class="top-header">Welcome</h1>
<p class="top-text">Hello world!</p>
<p class="topcontent">Are you learning CSS?</p>
```

[class^="top"] will select the three of them.

[class|="top"] will select only the two first elements. The last `<p>` has the class `topcontent` and therefore the selector won't find the isolated word `top`

Comment: Thanks , I aso want to know what is the difference between [attribute~="value"] and [attribute*="value"]

Comment: Similar answer: one selects only whole words, the other just looks for the value. Example:

`<div class="first_block">`  
`<div class="block active">`  
`<div class="other-block">`  
`<p class="myblock">`  

[class*="block"] will select all the elements.  
[class~="block"] will select only the second element (class "block")

Answer (score 0):

You can find (usually) more detailed documentation in [Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) or the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors) which should be a base for browser implementations.

```
[attr|=value]
```

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value can be
>   exactly value or can begin with value immediately followed by a
>   hyphen, - (U+002D). It is often used for language subcode matches.

Meaning it either matches `value` or `value-more-text` (value followed by `-`)

```
[attr^=value]
```

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is
>   prefixed (preceded) by value.

Meaning it is more loose than the previous selector as it matches an attribute that begins with `value` and can be followed by any other characters.